# Is it possible to suppress the top level in a reference to a derived type?

Tags: fortran

This is hard to describe in words but an example should make it clear.  Let's say I have a variable of a derived type, with the following components.

```
x%length
x%width
```

Is there any automatic way to refer to these without the top level?  In other words to refer to them as simply

```
length
width
```

Of course, I could first do

```
length => x%length
width  => x%width
```

for ALL individual components of the derived type.  But my use case involves thousands of variables, so I'd prefer not to do it that way.

As an example from another language, python will essentially allow this suppression with:

```
from x import *
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a functionality in fortran as far as I know, at least in the implementations that I have at hand. Beside that, the objectives of my post is to make some other thinks clear.

The python `from x import *` is the equivalent of `use x` in fortran. I am not very pythonic, but I do not think that you can import member of a class directly. So, that works as long as x is a pyton module, not a python class to my limited knowledge. `use x` will also works as long as `x` is a fortran module.

One of the programming language that I know of and that implements the feature that you are after is `pascal`. There is this handy construct `with` that allows you to do that.

```
with x do
begin
    lenght ....
    width ....
end
```

Indeed, it is very helpful in that it allows you to strip a part of the object name and get directly to fields. I loved it when I was using `pascal`, but it's been a long time.

`Delphi` certainly allows that too.

Comment: @JohnE, I understand that having the derived type in the first place was to carry every thing in one single variable. I wanted to point out that the analogy with python was not really what you described. However, I understood it clearly becaused I have used such a feature in another language, `pascal`.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I only meant the example in terms of `from x import *` as opposed to `import x`.  I agree it's not a perfect analogy to fortran, just the closest I could come up with to help illustrate the point.

Answer (score 2):

How about the Fortran 2003 associate construct? This will, in a sense, manage for you the pointer assignments that you listed:

```
Program test
  Type :: t
    Integer :: length
    Integer :: width
  End Type
  Type (t) :: x = t(42, 43)
  Associate (length=>x%length, width=>x%width)
    Print *, length, width
  End Associate
End Program
```

Quoting from Fortran 2003 (e.g., at http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/04/04-007.pdf): "The ASSOCIATE construct associates named entities with expressions or variables during the execution of its block."

The December 2015 ACM Fortran Forum "Compiler Support" article lists the associate construct as being fully supported by Cray, IBM, Intel and NAG and partially supported by gfortran.

I don't think there is any way to simplify this though if you have many type components to alias in this way.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure this is much of a practical improvement over pointers (although there is a convenient temporary aspect to them), but it's good to know about anyway.